# MAX function not working in Oracle statement

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have the following statement using MAX(woq.wq_version) and it keeps returning two results.

```sql
SELECT woq.wo_number, woq.quote_amount, MAX(woq.wq_version) version
  FROM ba_view_wo_quote woq
  LEFT JOIN sm_header smh
    ON woq.woo_auto_key = smh.woo_auto_key
 WHERE woq.woo_auto_key = smh.woo_auto_key
   AND woq.wo_number = 'WO1110885'
   AND woq.quote_amount <> '0' 
HAVING woq.wq_version = MAX(woq.wq_version)
 GROUP BY woq.wq_version, woq.quote_amount, woq.wo_number
```

I keep receiving these results:

| wo_number | quote_amount | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WO1110885 | 2803.15 | 1 |
| WO1110885 | 1200 | 2 |

Comment: Please include the full query.

Comment: I think you’ve got a bit confused with the `having` clause. You are grouping by the columns we can see including the column you are maxing, so the max isn’t able to do anything. Instead you probably want to just use `order by quote_amount desc` and `fetch first 1 row only`.

Comment: My apologies, here is the full SQL:

select woq.wo_number,woq.quote_amount,MAX(woq.wq_version) version from ba_view_wo_quote woq
     left join sm_header smh on woq.woo_auto_key=smh.woo_auto_key
     where WOQ.WOO_AUTO_KEY = SMH.WOO_AUTO_KEY and woq.wo_number = 'WO1110885'
      and woq.quote_amount<>'0'
     having woq.wq_version=max(woq.wq_version)
     group by woq.wq_version,woq.quote_amount,woq.wo_number

Comment: I need to fetch the highest quote version.

Comment: Why did you repeatedly write the line `woq.woo_auto_key = smh.woo_auto_key`, and what's the version for the DB?

Comment: This query cannot return a result because `having` should follow after `group by`. This query should cause syntax error

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want

```
select woq.wo_number,
       woq.quote_amount,
       woq.wq_version version 
  from ba_view_wo_quote woq 
       left join sm_header smh on woq.woo_auto_key=smh.woo_auto_key 
 where woq.wo_number = 'WO1110885' 
   and woq.quote_amount<>'0' 
 order by woq.quote_amount desc
 fetch first 1 row only
```

If that isn't what you're looking for, it would be helpful to update your question with a reproducible test case that shows us what your tables look like, what your data looks like, and what results you want for that data.

Note that it doesn't make sense to duplicate the same condition in the `on` clause of your join and in the `where` clause so I got rid of the `where` clause condition.

Comment: When i run the statement above, I am getting this error. Is it working on your side?

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 2

Comment: I believe fetch is not working because I am running 11g.

Comment: Any ideas as to what else I can use in Oracle besides FETCH?